# Where do I find the effect window in illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I can't find the windows in the picture below in adobe illustrator 2015. How do I find it ?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

There is no such thing in *any* currently released version of Illustrator (cc2017 as of this writing).

That screenshot is the **Photoshop Layer Styles dialog window**.